# How to Write to SD Card at high rate?

Tags: spi, sd, fat, card

I have just started working on interfacing Nordic semiconductor's nrf52 with SD card using SDK 12.0. I have to write to SD card at a rate of 84 packets per second and each packet consists of 20 bytes. I am using fat file system which uses SPI protocol for writing to SD card.

I am sampling the ADC at 1 ksps (12 bit resolution)and storing these samples in SD card.Here I am writing to SD card based on GPIO interrupt For each write operation I am using following steps: 1)open directory 2)open file 3)write bytes to file 4)close the file.

While writing continuously I am facing following issues :

1) Code gets restarted automatically after writing some kb's into SD card.

2) I am wring only in one file. Still additional files are generated in SD card.

3) while writing to file somewhere in the middle I am getting massage as Unable to open or create file: ank.TXT.

I am using 8 GB SD card for this operation. IAR version 7.4 and SDK 12.0. Does any one has any idea why I am getting these issues?

I have attached my code at [this link](https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/question/107383/how-to-write-to-sd-card-at-high-rate/?comment=107469#comment-107469)

have to write to SD card whole data at longer duration without restarting the code.

Comment: 1.7 kB/s is not a high data rate. I can routinely write over 52 kB/s from a 100MHz Arm M3 over SPI to FAT formated SD card (6x32 bit ADC + 1x16 bit value + timestamp all at 2 kHz). The hardware is easily capable of what you want. Check your SPI bus frequency, ensure it is up at 5-10MHz. Beyond that I'm voting to close this, it is purely a software issue and nothing to do with electronics.

Comment: Perhaps if you didn't discard the error code from `f_open`, you'd know why your software fails to open the file. The rest cannot be answered since you only posted one function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I take back my earlier comment. You do have an electronics issue. What you failed to mention in your question but is visible in the link you have now provided is that when you get multiple files the names are gibberish, they are the result of file system corruption rather than something actively creating files.

This is happening because you are not supplying sufficient power to the SD card. When you perform a write the current draw of the card jumps up rapidly, if the power supply is insufficient this causes the voltage supplied to the card to dip temporarily causing the write to fail and corrupting the file system. This shows up as random gibberish files/directories being created or sometimes the entire card becoming unusable and requiring a reformat.

Check your wiring and verify the SD card is getting a good solid 3.3V supply with low impedance connections from the socket to the power supply. Adding extra capacitance to ground right on the power pin of the SD socket will also help.

Comment: I fail to see anything in the question to support your guess. If anything, I bet there's heap corruption or stack overflow somewhere in the code, smashing the file name variable.

Comment: As I said if you read my answer it's not in the question. It's in the link to the code that is near the end of the question. There is a screen shot of the directory listing. I've had this exact problem before which is why I recognize the result. Please don't down vote answers just because they don't agree with your guesses.

Comment: So what? I have seen similar results when not enough memory was allocated for the stack. How do you tell between stack overflow and power failure?

Comment: I can't tell the difference. However given how simple his code is memory issues are unlikely. I do however know that power supply issues are a possible cause that matches the symptoms exactly. I could well be wrong however this is an electronics board, I have pointed out an electronics solution that fits all of the supplied information. I'm confused as to how that is considered unhelpful or how you could be so sure that it's not the cause.

Comment: I believe 59,6 KB of C code is plenty to have memory corruption issues.

Comment: I repeat, how are you so sure that it's not the power? Saying that something is wrong because there are other possible explanations is both unhelpful and illogical.

Comment: "I'm confused as to how that is considered unhelpful" - because PSU issues is like Russel's teapot: whatever the error is, PSU issues can't be ruled out. Should we post "Oh, and get a solid power supply" answer under every other question?

Comment: Whereas "heap corruption or stack overflow somewhere" is highly specific? My initial response was that it was software. And then I saw that the type of corruption he was seeing is exactly what you get when an SD card browns out during a write. Which means if nothing else the power supply should be checked under load.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reply. As per your suggestion, the additional files created in the SD card may be because of power supply issue. Do I need to connect pull resistor to each SPI pin to avoid this issue.

Comment: My another concern is related to restarting of my code. Using the code that I have attached in above link, I am unable to write the ADC samples for longer duration at 1000 samples per second rate.After writing some KB's of information entire code getting restarted. Does the steps that I am following for file writing are proper?

Comment: @ankushjamthikar pull-ups won't fix a power supply issue. Please post details/pictures of the hardware rather than the code so that it's possible to tell if this is the problem or not.